Openpyxl - Merge same cells in column from pandas
I'm trying to output a Pandas dataframe into an Excel file using openpyxl:
I would like to merge multiple rows of each ID of a dataframe into a single cell use openpyxl.
I have the following list of columns and Dataframe in pandas respectively
dict1 = {'ID': ['6610', '6610', '6610', '6620', '6620', '7540', '7540'],
 'NEW_ID': ['6615', '6615', '6615', '   ', '   ', 'nan', 'nan'],
 'OLD_PRICE': [17.22, 17.9, 17.22, 27.49, 20.42, 30.73, 29.55],
 'NEW_PRICE': [17.22, 17.22, 27.49, 18.99, 27.49, 29.55, 27.49],
 'LABEL': ['  NaN1', '  NaN2', '  NaN4', 'nan', '  Na', 'A', 'B']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)


The workbook looks now:
BEFORE:

I am trying to get it to look in the end:
AFTER:

